# Given a URL, is there a way to determinate which file were downloaded from there?

Tags: c#, ads

I hope to be as clear as possible:
with ADS, I can retrieve the file Zone.Identifier:
from `cmd`, after `Dir /R`, I can launch `notepad file.extension:Zone.Identifier` and I can read the `ReferrerUrl/HostUrl`. But, given a URL, there is a way, better if in C#, to retrieve the file name in my filesystem downloaded from this URL?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

If the response contains a [`Content-Disposition`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Content-Disposition) header, it will look like this:

```
Content-Disposition​: attachment; filename=opensearch.osdx​
```

On navigating to the url, a file with the name `opensearch.osdx` will be downloaded

Comment: Hi, thanks for your responde, but I want something that:
for example I have an IP address. I want to know which file already in my filesystem was downloaded from that IP